# can InputMismatchException work for java GUI?

Tags: java

In my code, I have 2 exception handling which are InputMismatchException and Exception. The problem I facing right now is the exception handling of InputMismatchException doesn't work and it only works for Exception.

[output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LDQz.png)

below is my source code

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
       try {     
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        double cm = Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
        double kg = Double.parseDouble(tf2.getText());
        double BMI=0;
        double m = cm/100;
        if(e.getSource() == btCalc) {
            BMI = kg / (m * m); 
        }             
        tfBMI.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(BMI))); 
        
       }  
       catch(InputMismatchException  e1) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"You must enter a number. Please try again.");
       }
      catch(Exception e2) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please Enter your Height and Weight");
       } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why do you think your code throws an `InputMismatchException`? Which line should do that?

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble` throws a [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html), not an `InputMismatchException`. Change your `catch` clause accordingly and you should be OK.